# CMake autogenerated Makefile on ubuntu 16.04 docker image prepending "//" to targets

Tags: makefile, docker, cmake

I have a docker image built as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER xyz
COPY apt.conf /etc/apt/
RUN apt-get -y update 
RUN apt-get -y  install cmake
RUN apt-get -y install libc++-dev
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential
RUN apt-get -y install beignet opencl-headers
RUN apt-get -y install mlocate
RUN updatedb
RUN mkdir /usr/local/code
COPY code /usr/local/code
RUN mkdir /usr/local/build
RUN cmake /usr/local/code/
CMD make
```

The Makefile autogenerated by CMake has an all target as below:

all:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 //all

Why is CMake adding this extra "//" before all?

running make fails because it cannot find rule associated with target //all

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '//all'.  Stop.
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The same Makefile autogenerated on a different machine with Ubuntu (without the "//")works fine. Please advise.

Comment: CMakeLists.txt, please.

Comment: This worked fine when built out of source using the WORKDIR command.